# Properties of t-values

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Does anyone know what the properties of t-values are?

As I know it's just the ration
$$t=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$$
which follows a t-distribution.

Used in mean-comparison tests and as a consequence also to check the significance of single independent variables in regression analysis. To generalize, t-values are used for hypothesis testing.
Am I right with these properties?
Thanks!

Comment: a $t$-value or $t$-statistic in a hypothesis test is calculated when we want to make an inference about a normally (or approximately normally) distributed population mean when the variance of the population is unknown.  In this sense, its usage in linear regression arises naturally from the assumption that the regression error is normally distributed with mean zero and some unknown variance $\sigma^2$.  In both cases, the unbiased estimate of the population variance is $s^2$, and the standardized test statistic is therefore $t$ distributed with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

I think of properties as intrinsic to something, not as a function of how it is used. To rattle off a few properties:

1. It approaches cauchy distribution as df $\rightarrow0$
2. Is approaches a normal (0,1) distrbution as df $\rightarrow \infty$
3. It is symmetric and relatively light tailed compared to a normal RV with equivalent mean and variance (not to be confused with the fact that it produces *wider* confidence intervals)